# Will gravity affect a ball moving horizontally across the floor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, projectile, spring

I was solving an exam when I came across this question:

> A compressed spring projects a ball horizontally in a vacuum chamber. On the Earth, the ball reaches the chamber floor 4.0 m in front of the spring.An identical experiment is done on the Moon. The gravitational field strength is lower on the
> Moon than on the Earth.
> The experimental results on the Moon are compared with those on the Earth.
> Which statement is correct?

> A) The horizontal speed is greater on the Moon and the ball hits the floor 4.0 m in front of the
> spring.

> B) The horizontal speed is greater on the Moon and the ball hits the floor more than 4.0 m in
> front of the spring.

> C) The horizontal speed is the same on the Moon and the ball hits the floor 4.0 m in front of the
> spring.

> D) The horizontal speed is the same on the Moon and the ball hits the floor more than 4.0 m in
> front of the spring.

The correct Answer is D. But why would the ball stop, shouldn't it continue moving because of its inertia. And since air resistance doesn't play any rule here, as the experiment is carried out in a vacuum chamber, the ball must stop due to gravity. The thing is the ball is moving horizontally across the floor why should gravity affect the ball then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of things you seem to have misread in the question:

1. The ball is not being horizontally projected across the floor. Instead, the ball is being horizontally projected from mid-air. It then falls towards the floor due to gravity.
2. When the experiment is done on Earth, it hits the floor 4.0 m "in front of" the spring, that is, the horizontal distance between the spring and the point of the first impact of the ball on the floor is 4.0 m. Note that the ball does not stop at a distance of 4.0 m. Indeed, unless it's something like a ball of clay that can be expected to have a perfectly inelastic collision, the ball will continue to move forward due to inertia.

Perhaps this will be enough for you to get on the right track?

Comment: Re, "mid-air," Ha ha! But the question explicitly says that there is no air in the experiment. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The time required for the ball to reach the floor is determined by the acceleration of gravity.  On the moon, gravity is weaker and the ball has more time to travel horizontally before hitting the floor.